# Unity javascript error Rigidbody

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
 #pragma strict

 private Rigidbody rb;

function Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

function FixedUpdate () {
    var v : float = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    var h : float = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (h, 0.0f, v);
    rb.AddForce (movement);
}
```

i would appreciate an answer with some code to show me. Thanks for taking your time to reply.

Comment: So, what's the error?

Comment: Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.js(3,10): BCE0043: Unexpected token: Rigidbody.

Comment: ohh. and this one Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.js(13,16): UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end. You can clearly see the semi-colon after v)

Comment: Ok. Check my answer. Please learn C# if you want to be programming in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Javascript with C# in your code. They are two different languages.  Here are the problems:

`private Rigidbody rb;` , `rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();`, and `Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (h, 0.0f, v);`.

I would suggest you switch to C# immediately because Unity recommends you do so. Most of the newest documentation does not have examples for Javascript and it looks like Javascript support will be removed in the coming future.

I commented out the bad codes so you can learn from your mistake. Here is your fixed code:

```
#pragma strict

//private Rigidbody rb;
private var rb:Rigidbody;

function Start () {
    //rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb = GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
}

function FixedUpdate () {
    var v : float = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    var h : float = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    //Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (h, 0.0f, v);
    var movement = Vector3(h, 0.0f, v);
    rb.AddForce (movement);
}
```